# Retrieving hosts from a URL list using Perl's Regexp::Common::URI::http library

Tags: regular-expression, perl, url

Presently I'm getting a list of URLs from a text file like so:

```bsh
perl -MRegexp::Common=URI -nE 'say $& while /$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-scheme => "https?"}/g' urls.txt
```

And am wondering how to get only the `host` field. The [package documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::URI::http#DESCRIPTION) mentions a `-keep` parameter, but the [source implementation](https://metacpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/source/lib/Regexp/Common/URI/http.pm) does not show it as being available.

I'm aware that my desired output can be achieved by piping the output to other programs and handling it, but is it possible to achieve what I want in this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the source implementation does not show it as being available.

It is not implemented in Regexp::Common::URI but inherited from Regexp::Common. And using this parameter works as documented:

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=URI -nE \
  'say $3 while /$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-scheme => "https?"}{-keep}/g' \
  urls.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! As a side question if you wouldn't mind helping, is there any way to get capture the `$hostname` expression from the RFC2396 specification? The `$host` captures both a domain or IPv4 address.

Comment: @T145: I don't see an obvious way with the module to  get only hostname not IPv4.